# Accessing the same @SessionScoped CDI bean from inside a Servlet and a Session Bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly-8

I've seen that there are a couple of similar questions here in SO, but none of them really helped me.

Straight to the point, I'm working in Eclipse and I have an EAR deployed on Wildfly8 with this structure:

- **ZeroCDI**, a java standalone project with this class

  ```
  @SessionScoped
  public class MyUser implements Serializable{
      private static final long serialVersionUID = -8247101999419229162L;
      private String name;

      public void setAndPrintName(String name) {
          System.out.println("Object = "+this);
          System.out.println("Old name = "+this.name);
          this.name = name;
          System.out.println("New name = "+this.name);
      }
  }
  ```
- **ZeroWEB**: the web module of the ear, where *ZeroCDI* is added in the Deployment Assembly section. It has this only servlet

  ```
  @WebServlet("/ZeroServlet")
  public class ZeroServlet extends HttpServlet {
      ...
      @Inject MyUser user;
      @EJB UserService userService;

      protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          user.setAndPrintName("foo");
          userService.setCurrentUser("bar");
      }
      ...
  }
  ```
- **ZeroEJB**: the EJB module of the ear, where *ZeroCDI* is added in the Deployment Assembly section. It has this only EJB

  ```
  @Stateless
  @LocalBean
  public class UserService {

      public UserService() {}

      @Inject MyUser user;
      public void setCurrentUser(String username){
          user.setAndPrintName(username);
      }

  }
  ```
- **ZeroEAR**: the archive wrapping two modules (WEB and EJB) and the library *ZeroCDI.jar*

Running the application I can see that servlet and ejb are not referencing the same object:

```
16:19:50,674 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Object = nets.devsedge.beans.MyUser@596ab996
16:19:50,674 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Old name = null
16:19:50,674 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) New name = foo
16:19:50,701 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Object = nets.devsedge.beans.MyUser@579a2f59
16:19:50,702 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Old name = null
16:19:50,702 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) New name = bar
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't my session scoped bean instance be shared in the same session through the entire application? Why a new instance is being injected in the EJB instead?

Comment: It is a design smell as sharing HTTP sessions across Web and EJB modules is considered to be a bad design for the obvious reason. What if you changed the given stateless local EJB to a remote EJB on a remote EE server? The approach would be impractical.

Comment: @Tiny so you're saying that before even worrying about how to do it, it's a bad design idea sharing CDI beans between different modules?

Comment: In a nutshell, an EJB module must not have any dependency from its associated web module. In other words, an EJB module, the service layer containing business logic must not know anything about its associated clients - it should be used / accessed by any valid client - not only web (remote desktop clients like Swing / AWT may also be there). The web module (or application client) is however, loosely-coupled with the EJB module (mostly dependency injections only). Another different approach is acceptable depending upon the functional / technical requirements.

Comment: @Tiny that's something that definitely makes sense...

Comment: Take a few lessons in Layered Architectures. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx